# Shift a semi-log chart

Tags: matlab, charts

There are two related things I would like to ask help with. 
1) I'm trying to shift a "semi-log" chart (using `semilogy`) such that the new line passes through a given point on the chart, but still ***appears to be parallel*** to the original. 
2) Shift the "line" exactly as in 1), but then also invert the slope.

I think that the desired results are best illustrated with an actual chart.

Given the following code:

```
x = [50 80];
y = [10 20];

all_x = 1:200;

P = polyfit(x, log10(y),1);
log_line = 10.^(polyval(log_line,all_x));

semilogy(all_x,log_line)
```

I obtain the following chart:
[image: chart 1]

For 1), let's say I want to move the line such that it passes through point (20,10).  The desired result would look something like the orange line below (please note that I added a blue dot at the (20,10) point only for reference):

[image]

For 2), I want to take the line from 1) and take an inverse of the slope, so that the final result looks like the orange line below:

[image]

Please let me know if any clarifications are needed.

EDIT: Based on Will's answer (below), the solution is as follows:

```
%// to shift to point (40, 10^1.5)

%// solution to 1)
log_line_offset = (10^1.5).^(log10(log_line)/log10(10^1.5) + 1-log10(log_line(40))/log10(10^1.5));

%// solution to 2)
log_line_offset_inverted = (10^1.5).^(1 + log10(log_line(40))/log10(10^1.5) - log10(log_line)/log10(10^1.5));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do transformations described as linear operations on logarithmic axes, perform those linear transformations on the logarithm of the values and then reapply the exponentiation. So for 1):

```
log_line_offset = 10.^(log10(log_line) + 1-log10(log_line(20)));
```

And for 2):

```
log_line_offset_inverted = 10.^(2*log10(log_line_offset(20)) - log10(log_line_offset));
```

or:

```
log_line_offset_inverted = 10.^(1 + log10(log_line(20)) - log10(log_line));
```

These can then be plot with `semilogy` in the same way:

```
semilogy(all_x,log_line,all_x, log_line_offset, all_x,log_line_offset_inverted)
```

[image: Result]

I can't guarantee that this is a sensible solution for the application that you're creating these plots and their underlying data though. It seems an odd way to describe the problem, so you might be better off creating these offsets further up the chain of calculation.

For example, `log_line_offset` can just as easily be calculated using your original code but for an `x` value of `[20 50]`, but whether that is a meaningful way to treat the data may depend on what it's supposed to represent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is definitely on the right track to what I need. How would I need to modify your code to make the line pass through a point like `(40, 10^1.5)` or `(40, 10^1.6)`?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. For the `(40, 10^1.5)` point it would be: `log_line_offset = (10^1.5).^(log10(log_line)/log10(10^1.5) + 1-log10(log_line(40))/log10(10^1.5));` Similar for the other point. Need to test this a bit more.

Comment: That works in a sort of roundabout way. However you are essentially converting the `1` from being in a base-10 log space to a base-1.5 log space, just so that the offset it creates is equivalent to `1.5` in the base-10 log space that the axes use. Much easier just to change the `1` to `1.5`! `log_line_offset = 10.^(log10(log_line) + 1.5-log10(log_line(40)));`